# Transfering proof from Z to N in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, formal-verification

Is there a way in Coq in to prove a statement for integer numbers and the transfer statement in a semi-automatic way to naturals?

For a concret example, take the following lemma:

```
Lemma cancellation:
  forall a b c: nat, a > 0 -> a * b = a * c -> b = c.
```

The statement is actually true in Z. In this case, it is easier to prove, because one can use subtraction to get `a * (b - c) = 0` and then simplify `a`. But subtraction for naturals is capped, hence this would not work.

Assume I can prove this for integers. Is there some tactic that one could use to derive the statement for naturals as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is a tactic called `zify` that automatically turns a goal manipulating naturals into a goal manipulating integers (e.g., by inserting appropriate calls to `Z.of_nat`). This tactic is internally called by `lia`, but does not seem to be well documented. It is at least mentioned [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html#id7).

In your case, this would give the following.

```
Require Import ZArith.

(* The lemma stated in Z. *)
Lemma cancellation:
  (forall a b c, a > 0 -> a * b = a * c -> b = c)%Z.
Proof.
  (* your favorite proof of this result *)
Admitted.

(* The lemma stated in nat. *)
Lemma cancellation_nat:
  forall a b c: nat, a > 0 -> a * b = a * c -> b = c.
Proof.
  intros.
  zify.
  eauto using cancellation.
Qed.
```